# Visual Studio Esproj - Debug only launching esproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've a solution with 2 projects, .net7 api and a vue esproj

When I set the startup project as the .net 7 api, Visual Studio changes to the .esproj and launches it instead of the api.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: You may have a project in your solution that depends on another project, and you set the dependent project's startup project. This means that when you start a dependent project, Visual Studio automatically starts the dependent project as well. But your information is not enough for us to solve your problem. Try to recreate the minimal implementation use case and provide it to us, you may solve the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: I think i found out the problem. I've deleted the user settings from solution and got it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a project in the solution that depends on another project, and you set the startup project of the dependent project. This means that when you start a dependent project, Visual Studio automatically starts the dependent project as well.

Apparently you have some wrong settings in your user settings.

So the fix for this issue is to remove the user settings from the solution and run again.